# Convert zip lists to a txt file without using any libraries

Tags: python, list, file

```
for (a, b, c, d, e, f, g) in zip(A, B, C, D, E, F, G):
    result = ''.join([a,b,c,d,e,f,g])

# Write the file
with open("file.txt","w") as f:
    f.write(result)
```

This only gives one line instead of the whole result. The type of the result is shown below. May I know how to convert the whole result to a txt file? Thanks a lot.

```
<class 'str'>

<class 'str'>

<class 'str'>

<class 'str'>

<class 'str'>

<class 'str'>

<class 'str'>

<class 'str'>

<class 'str'>

<class 'str'>

<class 'str'>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `f.write(result)` in the loop. And append a newline to each line.

```
with open("file.txt","w") as f:
    for data in zip(A, B, C, D, E, F, G):
        result = ''.join(data)
        f.write(result + '\n')
```

There's no need to spread the zipped tuples into variables if you're just going to combine them back into a list. Just use the tuples directly.